# include php template в функцию umi

Tags: шаблоны, umi

Никак не удается по другому сделать , чтобы результат работы функции выводился уже отрендеренным в шаблоне.
Планирую эту функцию вызывать через ajax. С вызовом функции umi через ajax проблем нет.

А вот шаблон в функцию думаю применить уже с помощью функции include().

Понимаю что это наверно неправильно, но по другому никак.

Comment: похоже на дубль вот [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/833334/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-tpl-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-umi-cms) вопроса

Comment: я про tpl шаблонизатор спрашивал. с umi беда какая то ,