# Не подгружается tpl шаблонизатор в макросе umi.cms

Tags: tpl, umi

Содержимое макроса упростил для исключения других ошибок.

Макрос:

```
public function getDeliveryAjax($template = 'default') {

    list(
    $templateBlock,
    $templateLineItem,
    $templateMapItem,
    $templateJavascript
    ) = def_module::loadTemplates('emarket/delivery/'.$template, 
    'delivery_tab_block',
    'delivery_line_item',
    'delivery_map_item',
    'delivery_javascript'
    );

    $block_arr['attribute:delivery_line_items']       = 'text1';
    $block_arr['attribute:delivery_map_items']        = 'text2';
    $block_arr['attribute:delivery_javascript_items'] = 'text3';

    return def_module::parseTemplate($templateBlock, $block_arr);
}
```

Шаблон default.tpl, находится по пути tpls/emarket/delivery/default.tpl:

```
<?php
$FORMS = Array();

$FORMS['delivery_tab_block'] = <<<END
 <div>

 <table class="b-order_delivery">
    %delivery_line_items%
 </table>

 <table class="b-order_delivery">
    %delivery_map_items%
 </table>

  <div id="map">
      %delivery_javascript_items%
   </div>

</div>
END;
```

Запускаю по ссылке через браузер: 
http://site.ru/udata/emarket/getDeliveryAjax

На выходе получаю:

```
<udata xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/TR/xlink" delivery_line_items="text1" delivery_map_items="text2" delivery_javascript_items="text3" module="emarket" method="getDeliveryAjax" generation-time="1.222877"/>
<!--
 This page generated in 2.299103 secs by XSLT, HTTP SCHEME MODE 
-->
```

Как вывести данные макроса вместе с шаблоном?

Все делаю на примере других макросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Для php-шаблонизатора использую такой код:**

```
public function getDeliveryAjax() {
    // ваш код
    $template = 'emarket/delivery/default';
    $currentTemplater = cmsController::getInstance()->getCurrentTemplater();
    $templatesSource = $currentTemplater->getTemplatesSource();
    $templater = new umiTemplaterPHP($templatesSource);
    $buffer = OutputBuffer::current('HTTPOutputBuffer');
    $buffer->push($templater->render($result, $template));
    $buffer->end();
    return $result;
}
```

И кладем php-шаблон в файл emarket/delivery/default.phtml

Вызываем, как site.ru/emarket/getDeliveryAjax/

Comment: к сожалению не работают оба варианта

Comment: У меня сайт на phtml шаблонах, я хочу по вызову макроса получать , отрендеренный блок вместе с html разметкой. При этом не пихая html разметку в сам макрос. И планирую макрос вызывать из ajax.

Comment: а вот информацию про php-шаблонизатор стоило сразу публиковать. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Во. спасибо! больше месяца искал решение данной задачи. А где это описано , в документации я такого и рядом не находил?

Comment: это я из исходников где-то вытащил